# Excel combobox dropdown items based on the previous combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Form will accept information and then copy the info to Sheet1.
The form contains 5 textbox and 2 combobox.  1st combobox options are CRIS, TRACS, and DOCS.  2nd combobox option should be based on the 1st combobox selection.

[image: Form Design]

Here's my code so far:

```
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMove_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

Sheet1.Activate     'Make Sheet1 active

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1      

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = txtName.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = txtBtn.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtCbr.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = txtOrder.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = txtTrouble.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ComboBox1.Value

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

txtName.Value = ""          'Empty NameTextBox
txtBtn.Value = ""           'Empty BTN
txtCbr.Value = ""           'Empty CBR
txtOrder.Value = ""         'Empty Order Number
txtTrouble.Value = ""       'Empty Trouble Ticket Number

ComboBox1.Clear

With ComboBox1
   .AddItem "CRIS"
   .AddItem "TRACS"
   .AddItem "DOCS"
End With

txtName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sir.  Thank you for your quick response too.  It's in my screenshot where we can find the data to be filled in the 2nd combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in your userform code pane:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Me
        If .ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
            Select Case .ComboBox1.Value
                Case "CRIS"
                    .ComboBox2.List = Array("close", "reroute", "transfer")
                Case "TRACS"
                    .ComboBox2.List = Array("close", "reroute")
                Case "DOCS"
                    .ComboBox2.List = Array("completed", "transfer", "update")
            End Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks user3598756 for quick response.  It works better now.

Comment: Thank it helps. I also got this code from a friend, it looks quite the same.