# Automatic count the number of entry depending on what selected in ComboBox1

Tags: excel, vba, macros, counter

Continue with my last question here - [Excel combobox dropdown items based on the previous combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927694/excel-combobox-dropdown-items-based-on-the-previous-combobox/39929132?noredirect=1#comment67157521_39929132)

I added 4 TextBox for CRIS, TRACS, DOCS, and TOTAL.
I wanted to have a visible counter that populate depeding on what selection I choose in ComboBox1 [Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s9o4.png)

```
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()

 Unload Me
 frmLogin.Show

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
 Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMove_Click()

 Dim emptyRow As Long

 Sheet1.Activate     'Make Sheet1 active

 emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1       'Determine emptyRow

 'Transfer information
 Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = txtName.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = txtBtn.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtCbr.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = txtOrder.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = txtTrouble.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ComboBox1.Value
 Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = ComboBox2.Value

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 Select Case ComboBox1.Text
    Case "TRACS"
        With ComboBox2
            .Clear
           .AddItem "Complete"
           .AddItem "Re-Route"
        End With
    Case "CRIS"
        With ComboBox2
            .Clear
           .AddItem "Close"
           .AddItem "Re-route"
           .AddItem "Transfer"
        End With

    Case "DOCS"
        With ComboBox2
            .Clear
           .AddItem "Completed"
           .AddItem "Follow-up"
           .AddItem "Reject"
        End With
 End Select
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 txtName.Value = ""          'Empty NameTextBox
 txtBtn.Value = ""           'Empty BTN
 txtCbr.Value = ""           'Empty CBR
 txtOrder.Value = ""         'Empty Order Number
 txtTrouble.Value = ""       'Empty Trouble Ticket Number

 ComboBox1.Clear
 ComboBox2.Clear

 With ComboBox1
   .AddItem "CRIS"
   .AddItem "TRACS"
   .AddItem "DOCS"
 End With

 txtName.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do things a little different:

```
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
    Unload Me
    frmLogin.Show
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    txtName.Value = ""          'Empty NameTextBox
    txtBtn.Value = ""           'Empty BTN
    txtCbr.Value = ""           'Empty CBR
    txtOrder.Value = ""         'Empty Order Number
    txtTrouble.Value = ""       'Empty Trouble Ticket Number
    ComboBox2.Clear
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1
    txtName.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMove_Click()
    With Sheet1
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1).Resize(1, 7).Value = Array(txtName.Value, txtBtn.Value, txtCbr.Value, txtOrder.Value, txtTrouble.Value, ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox2.Value)
        End With

        txtCRIS.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(6), "CRIS")
        txtTRACS.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(6), "TRACS")
        txtDOCS.Value = Application.CountIf(.Columns(6), "DOCS")
        txtTotal.Value = Application.Sum(txtCRIS.Value, txtTRACS.Value, txtDOCS.Value)

    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
    Case "TRACS"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Complete", "Re-Route")
    Case "CRIS"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Close", "Re-route", "Transfer")
    Case "DOCS"
        ComboBox2.List = Array("Completed", "Follow-up", "Reject")
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("CRIS", "TRACS", "DOCS")
    txtName.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sir Thomas Inzina, thank you so much for your quick response and yes it's absolutely working for me.  It counts now.  I have to fully understand the code line by line, that is my next priority.  I also wanted to reset the counter as this is on a daily basis.  I will add a date field in my tracker.  So that the next day it will be back to zero.  Once again thank you so much.